# Fade body away with simple javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a simple function to fade out the body onclick.
Can it be done with javascript? I can use jquery if there is no other choice.

Comment: Why did this get voted down? Its a perfectly valid question and he obv looked up how to do it with jquery already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the function you need to utilize is `setInterval` inorder to acheive a "fade-out" animation.

```
function fadeout ( element, duration ){
   element.style.opacity = element.style.opacity || 1;
   var inter = setInterval(function(inter){
       if( element.style.opacity <= 0 ){
           clearInterval(inter);
           block.style.display = "none";
       } else {
           element.style.opacity -= (1/(duration/13));
       }
    },13); 
}
```

check it in action on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmVJn/1/)

Comment: for those of you that think 13ms is too often, jQuery uses a 13ms interval by default

Answer (score 0):

You could write the function from scratch, but [jQuery's fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) would certainly be easier.